# CSS and JS not working over HTTPS in laravel

Tags: laravel, security, https

My CSS and JS file work fine on localhost but when up to host it not working.
I use laravel 5.4. I tried a lot of ways but still failed. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlP0A.png)

My embedded CSS and JS code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5O1L.png)

UPDATE: Thanks all i have fixed my problems follow this:
1. change http://localhost to https://localhost at APP_URL line in .env file
2. add \URL::forceScheme('https') to AppServiceProvider.php file in boot() function
3. the last is include {{asset('--link_on_href--')}} for each CSS and JS embeded on index.php

Comment: use asset helper like this, <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: arun kunmar: I have tried it but still error :(

Comment: You literally saved my day man! Your solution worked like WOW.
I have already done the 3rd point but starting 2 points are life-savers :)
Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `asset()` helper to include assets in your view. This will automatically generate the appropriate `URL` for the included files based on you `APP_URL` in your `.env` file.

**For CSS,**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**Or**

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**For JS,**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

**Or**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

**For Images and other such assets,**

```
{{ asset('img/photo.jpg'); }}
```

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#urls)